# Getting rigidbodies to react to force-fields

Tags: mesh, physics, force-fields, rigidbody

I am new to Blender, and am trying to make a physics sandbox.

My approach is to use rigidbodies that are attracted by force fields to form materials and structures.

My original approach to achieving this was to use force fields; however, force fields appear to not work on rigidbodies; two rigidbody force field generators fail to react to one another even when the strength is set to 100.

**Edit:** I tried with -1000 strength and 0.001lg mass, and it still does nothing except fall!

I then tried with softbodies. However, they crumple with seemingly no resistance, and this is not acceptable.

How do I get (fairly) rigid bodies to attract to one another?

**EDIT:** [Here is the Blend file](https://ufile.io/kohp5wvj). Hosted for 20 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rigid body, visit the Scene properties, Rigid Body World, and select the Collection that contains your force field.  Oddly -- whereas most blender physics will apply forces from ALL Collections if no specific Collection is specified -- Rigid Body World wants to ignore things unless you specify a collection:

[image]

Welcome to the blender world of sometimes un-intuitive workflow, Abdullah!

Here's an example with cube (mesh) and Icosphere (Convex Hull) [image]

Comment: It worked with a mesh cube, but didn't work with mesh icosphere. it also didn't work for either of the convex hulls.

Comment: I've tried with an icospehere and with convex hull.  I'm going to edit my above answer to include and you can download and compare my settings.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Though I press the accept button with some misgiving, because this has decreased my confidence in force fields.

Comment: @Abdullah -- welcome to Blender world, which -- along with 3ds Max -- leaves one pulling their hair, throwing salt over shoulder.  "Arcane"!  Example: this does not work the same way for Cloth fields!